# How to Clear/Reset a Postfix Queue

Tags: postfix, ubuntu-18.04

I recently discovered that one of our Ubuntu servers was generating dozens of notification emails a minute and throttling the Office 365 relay account it was sharing with a handful of other servers. I stopped the Postfix service on this server and disabled the scripts that were generating all of these alerts (and subsequent cascade of delivery failure messages). However, I didn't account for the Postfix Queue Manager which has retained thousands of these messages and attempts to send them all over again when I restart Postfix.

My first, admittedly bumbling, attempt to clear the queue was to navigate to the queue directory at `/var/spool/postfix` and manually remove files from the 'active' and 'incoming' folders. However, when I ran `postqueue -p` a ton of emails still showed up in the queue.

What is the best way to completely reset or purge a Postfix Queue?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You should use the `postsuper` command to delete messages from the Postfix queue - The `-d <queueid>` option would delete the message with the specified queue ID.

I'm using something like this script to run through all the messages in the mail queue:

```
mailq | awk '$7~/@/{print$1}' | while read qid; do postsuper -d $qid; done
```

Comment: how is this better than `-d ALL queuename ` ?

Comment: @anx Probably not? I usually use this loop for other - more complex - operations, and just co-opeted it for this use.

Comment: The `postsuper` command is indeed what I was looking for. Running `postsuper -d ALL` and then checking the queue contents gave confirmation that the mail queue on this system was indeed empty. I also ran `postsuper -p`, as suggested below to purge temporary files for good measure. Things are running smoothly again, thank you!

Answer (score 7):

Since you've gone an messed with the queue's files directly, you may want to issue a `postsuper -p`.

> **-p**  Purge old temporary files that are left over after system or software crashes.

---

Years ago a wrote a small script to better handle some cases in postfix mailqueues, rather than just doing ad hoc one liners. You might find it useful in the future.

`$ cat /usr/local/sbin/postclear`

```
#!/bin/bash

usage() {
        echo "${0/*\/} --from <address1> [<address2> .. <addressN>]"
        echo "${0/*\/} --bounce <address1> [<address2> .. <addressN>]"
        echo "${0/*\/} --to <address1> [<address2> .. <addressN>]"
}

if [ $# -lt 2 ]; then
        usage 1>&2 ;
        exit 1;
fi


case $1 in
        --from )
                shift
                while (( $# )) ; do
                        postqueue -p | grep -e "$1" | grep -Eo '^[A-F0-9]+' | postsuper -d -
                        shift
                done
                exit;;
        --bounce )
                shift
                while (( $# )) ; do
                        postqueue -p | grep -E -B2 -e "$1" | grep MAILER-DAEMON | grep -Eo '^[A-F0-9]+' | postsuper -d -
                        shift
                done
                exit;;
        --to )
                shift
                while (( $# )) ; do
                        postqueue -p | grep -E -B2 -e "$1" | grep -Eo '^[A-F0-9]+' | postsuper -d -
                        shift
                done
                exit;;
        * )
                echo "Unknown option $1" >&2
                exit 1;;
esac
```

Comment: Nice script :-). I would have used `awk` for both selecting the IDs and extracting them, but to each their own. I love your `while`s and am going to adopt this syntax - it is just gorgeous.

Comment: Indeed, thank you for sharing this bit of scripting!